# I get "undefined variable" PHP notice

Tags: php, notice

I'm curious as to why I'm getting an error on something I've done a million times before but am all of a sudden on a certain script getting an error 'Undefined variable: row'

Yet row seems defined to me...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="1" LIMIT 1 ';

$res = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) != FALSE) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    }
```

The above is pseudo sql... but I've checked that sql statement and I know its bringing out a result. I also know that $row is storing the data because if I go

```
echo $row[0];
```

I get the right data.

So to my knowledge, the $row variable is defined. Yet still - an error. Am I losing my mind or what am I missing here? Shouldn't this error/notice only occur if $row didn't exist?

---

### edit

Sorry guys its all happening INSIDE the if statement:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE uID="' . $ID . '" LIMIT 1 ';

$res = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($res) != FALSE) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$firstName = $row[0];

$lastName = $row[1];

$email = $row[2];

}
```

---

edit 2

if i do a print_r($row) I get the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Robert
[firstName] => Robert
[1] => Nibbles
[lastName] => Nibbles
[2] => robert@nibbles.com
[email] => robert@nibbles.com
)
Undefined variable: row
```

Comment: could you add the part of code that yields the mentioned error ?

Comment: Indeed, where is the error occurring? If it's outside the 'if' statement, then it's undefined.

Comment: inside the IF statement is the only place where $row is being used.

Comment: it certainly looks like you have a stray $row somewhere else...

Comment: thats what I thought as well but on doing a search in the file there is 4 instances and all 4 are in that if statement! i'm losing my marbles.

Comment: if i remove the above If statement and whats inside the error goes away. so it can't be any other $row somewhere else can it?

Comment: The error should tell what line.

Comment: It should - but it isn't. I've never seen this error before without a line number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't initialize `$row` to something outside that if statement, then it's undefined.

Otherwise, if you don't want to initialize `$row` to some kind of null value (not entirely unreasonable), you might want to surround any code that checks `$row` outside of the `if` statement with something like

```
if (isset($row))
  doSomething();
```

It's a pain, but you've just got to remember that any variables you don't define explicitly, even to null, are undefined and can lead to a runtime error if referenced as an rvalue in code (except in `isset` etc.). So in general, either always initialize your variables or liberally apply code like the above.

I apologize if this turns out not to be the issue, but I can't think of anything more than this without seeing your code.

EDIT: Sorry, it's "isset" not "defined". Been a while since I've actualy worked with PHP. I tried to answer the question with a concept, not syntax. My mistake.

Comment: `defined` doesn't do what you think here. You probably mean `isset`.

Comment: Damnation, that is precisely what I meant. Edit forthcoming in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Offtopic, but I recommend using [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) instead of mysql_fetch_array, then you can use the actual field names in your code, instead of some arbitrary numbers.

```
print $row[2]
```

vs

```
print $row['email];
```

Comment: cheers. but can't I do $row['email'] with mysql_fetch_array() as well can't I? I've just used $row[1] to for debugging purposes to make sure i haven't named the keys incorrectly or something

Comment: According to the mysql_fetch_array() page (http://us2.php.net/mysql_fetch_array), you can use either (the array has both numeric and associative indexing).

Personally, I would still favor mysql_fetch_assoc() in case that reduces overhead by only allowing one form of indexing. But I don't know the ins and outs of PHP well enough to know if this is worthwhile or not.